# Not able to open a downloaded SVG file containing D3JS tree

Tags: javascript, file, svg, d3.js, download

I managed to download a SVG file created using the following code

```
$('#download-SVG').click(function() {
    var dl = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(dl); // This line makes it work in Firefox.
    console.log(svg.node());
    dl.setAttribute("href", svgDataURL(svg.node()));
    dl.setAttribute("download", "test.svg");
    dl.click();
   });

function svgDataURL(svg) {
     var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
     var dataURL = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML);
     return dataURL;
   }
```

The file downloads, but does not open.  I suspect that the content of the dataURL has an issue

Below is a sample of the content of the dataURL content

```
data:image/svg+xml,%3Cg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20transform%3D%22translate(700%2C25)scale(.7%2C.7)%22%3E%3Cpath%20class%3D%22link%22%20d%3D%22M352.5%2C555C352.5%2C645%2022.5%2C645%2022.5%2C735%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20class%3D%22link%22%20d%3D%22M352.5%2C555C352.5%2C645%20132.5%2C645%20132.5%2C735%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20class%3D%22link%22%20d%3D%22M352.5%2C555C352.5%2C645%20242.5%2C645%20242.5%2C735%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20class%3D%22link%22%20d%3D%22M352.5%2C555C352.5%2C645%20352.5%2C645%20352.5%2C735%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20class%3D%22link%22%20d%3D%22M352.5%2C555C352.5%2C645%20462.5%2C645%20462.5%2C735%22%2F%3E%3
```

Appreciate any insight into the issue.

Comment: The svg used for the data URI begins with a group `<g>` not with a `<svg>` element. Also do not code the spaces. You can take a look at the code used for this [svg converter](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs)

Comment: Thank you @enxaneta for pointing out the issue.
Is there a way to embed the SVG tag in the svg content?  I have developed a genealogy tree based on Mike Bostock’s collapsible tree https://observablehq.com/@d3/collapsible-tree.

your example is cleaning the SVG data afterwards.  I would like to avoid that if possible, as I am not an experienced JavaScript or D3JS programmer.